# React particles not interacting on hover after adding an image in background?

Tags: reactjs, particles.js

I have the normal react particle code which works fine but after adding an image to the background the particles are not interacting on hover anymore. Image is in y.js file which is loaded in x.js file where react particles code exists

```
const ParticleOptions={

  particles: {
    number: {
      value: 170,
       density:{
        enable: true,
        value_area:850

      }  
    }
},

 interactivity:{
  detect_on:"canvas",
  events:{
    onhover:{
      enable:true,
      mode: "repulse"

    }
  },
   modes:{
    repulse:{
      distance:70,
      duration: 0.4
    }
   }
 }

}
```

My separate image in a different JS file:

```
return(
        <div className='abx'>

        <img src='https://samples.clarifai.com/face-det.jpg' alt=''/>

        </div>



        );
```

I expected thr interaction of particles on mouse movements to remain after adding a small image to the center but it does not

Answer (score 0):

Just change detect_on:"*canvas*",to *window*

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.